# What is the correct approach for connecting to 2 schemas from same project/service?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jdbc, database-connection

We have two schemas(say A and B) created in the Database which are being used from the same project.
Currently we are using the hibernate framework for schema 'A'.For the second schema,B, we are only establishing the connection as and when needed without hibernate framework,since we thought using hibernate for two schemas may make the application cumbersome.
What is the right approach for an application that would be in production and used in large scale ?Should we use hibernate for both the schemas?Please advise.